# Ternary condition with @lang in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I need to display yes/no equalents in my language based on a ternary condition.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
{{$data->letter_replied==1?@lang('global.yes'):@lang('global.no')}}
```

But i get:

```
FatalErrorException in 26fa959e3dcd793af9b6b658c5cb1d6b3fb1c3c4.php line 62:
syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

What is the right syntax I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to check condition in-line, you need to put them all in `(...)` as below.

```
{!!($data->letter_replied==1?'Yes':'No')!!}
```

Comment: This works but I need to display 'بله' for 'yes' if the language is 'Dari'!

Comment: No problem use `lang('yes')` and `lang('no')` or use `trans()` instead of `lang()`

Comment: `{!!($data->letter_replied==1?lang('yes'):lang('no'))!!}` gives: `Call to undefined function lang()`

Comment: You have to use `trans()`.